# Spring Boot - creating endpoints that involve more than one database table - what is the best practice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am doing a spring boot tutorial for fun. I understand that each entity can be defined by a model with a repository that the controller for that entity uses to create endpoints. I am wondering what is the best practice to create an endpoint in a controller that involves more than one model. I.e. we have a session model and speaker model below and i want to have a endpoint that returns all sessions with a speaker of a certain last name (many to many). Do I have to use both repositories? Is it even good practice to put this in session's controller since it also involves speaker? See the example below. Sorry if the question is stupid, I am trying to learn Spring-Boot and I am completely new to it.

```
//Session class
@Entity(name="sessions")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Session {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long session_id;
    private String session_name;
    private String session_description;
    private Integer session_length;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "session_speakers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="session_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "speaker_id"))
    private List<Speaker> speakers;
}

//Speaker
@Entity(name="speakers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Speaker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long speaker_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String title;
    private String company;
    private String speaker_bio;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "speakers")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Session> sessions;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/sessions")
public class SessionsController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public Session getSessionsBySpeakerName(@PathVariable String lname{
       //want to implement
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thhis would belong into the `SessionsController` because it is sessions that you are fetching. You only need the `SessionRepository` for this, just add a method to it, that fetches the sessions with the criteria you want. I'm not really sure if you can do this with a named query here, maybe you have to use the `@Query` annotation, or create a custom implementation with `Querydsl`  for example. A good practice that you can implement is to add a service layer for every logical entity you have, and only inject the services into other services instad of the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

`Controllers` are supposed to be very light,so it would be better to have seperate controllers.
Usualy it is good to have seperate `Repositories` also so that later on if you want to add a new table you would not be touching the existing stable code, it sould be loosly coupled as much as possible
Here are few blog posts which I found useful.

https://www.e4developer.com/2018/08/06/spring-boot-best-practices/

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-best-practices-for-microservices

https://www.javaguides.net/2019/03/spring-boot-best-practices.html